# No water dispensing after replacing Kenmore refrig filter

Tags: refrigerator, filter

After replacing the water filter on my side by side refrig (Kenmore model 106.51793 412) water dispenser will not work.  I removed and replaced it several times to make sure it was pushed in fully, still no water.  Reinserted old filter and dispenser still would not work. Water leaking out of water filter housing area at the bottom front of refrig.
Refrigerator is 5 yrs old.

Answer (score 1):

*Posted as a comment by [Lisa Powers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/150420/lisa-powers):*

The water filter housing part was worn out. I replaced it and the problem is fixed.